# Is using Redis a violation of REST principles?

Tags: rest, web-applications, redis

I am creating a webapp for data analysis. I want to use Redis to store the data that the user has uploaded so that I can send it to other pages/views. This data is only valid during the session and should expire when the session expires.

Is this a violation of REST principles? Or is this only a problem if I use some value that I have stored server side as session key/identifier?

Comment: How are you comparing REST with storing data in Redis ? Are you exposing the Redis port to the internet ?

Comment: The redis port is not exposed to the internet. Only the app server can write to it.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by this statement ? `Or is this only a problem if I use some value that I have stored server side as session key/identifier?` . I'll try to answer the question

Comment: What I mean is that I want to store the data that the user has uploaded during the current session. I do not want to save it to the MySQL DB yet. I also don't want the data to travel over HTTP with every request. The data is large ~ 10-50 MB. Hence, maybe I should store it in Redis during the session.
Now how do I look up the data from Redis? Should I use some key that the client sends? Something like a session ID?

Comment: Let me re-phrase what you're saying and tell me if that is correct. User uploads data (~ 50 MB). Your server doesn't want to store it in a DB but in a cache for temporary time but you want your client to have its link for this session. The item should expire if the session expires. So you're basically asking how would be able to keep track of the keys and if this is the right way to do it ?

Comment: You are right. I have been reading in the meanwhile. If the backend sends an ID for that data to the client and the client uses that, then it is RESTful. Am I right?

Comment: Answered it, In-short: yes

Comment: Just remember that REST is just stateless communication. Even if you needlessly send 50MB data again and again, then still it will be called REST. What you're doing is optimizing the communication :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your updates what you can do is to upload the data, generate a key against it, place it in Redis and keep it in `hash`(with meta data) or `list`(if there could be more than one upload). They `list/hash` key could be identified by the `user id`.

Then moving forward, let the client refer to this object using the generated id.

<strike>Actually one of the best practices is to use Redis over the internet is to expose a REST API and handle all communication using your Web Server. Redis is always kept in a secure network since Redis doesn't provide any security.</strike>

On Redis website

> ### Network security
>
> Access to the Redis port should be denied to everybody but trusted
>   clients in the network, so the servers running Redis should be
>   directly accessible only by the computers implementing the application
>   using Redis.
>
> In the common case of a single computer directly exposed to the
>   internet, such as a virtualized Linux instance (Linode, EC2, ...), the
>   Redis port should be firewalled to prevent access from the outside.
>   Clients will still be able to access Redis using the loopback
>   interface.

This is also a basic practice when using traditional databases.

Comment: Why is the text crossed? Was something changed in recent versions?

Comment: It was part of the answer that was irrelevant to the question.